# Insert into data fail after foreign key rebuilded.Mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I hava two table:IDCa and IDCb.At the beginning, each table has data and works fine. Table IDCb has foreign key sheetNum with IDCa's primary key sheetNum.

When I renamed IDCa to IDCabk,and drop IDCa, it worked failed.
So I runned: set foreign_key_checks=0
,  drop table IDCa, create table IDCa like IDCabk.

Now IDCa is empty.After that, I found IDCb's REFERENCES table had changed from IDCa to IDCabk. So I drop IDCb foreign key ,and readded like:

```
alter table IDCb add constraint fk_dvcOnsh foreign key (sheetNum) references IDCa(sheetNum);
```

After  I runned: set foreign_key_checks=1, and tried insert into data.But unfortunately,  it works fail.It seems nothing wrong.

Here IDCa information, run :show create table IDCa :

```
|IDCa        | CREATE TABLE `IDCa` (
`sheetNum` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 .........
 PRIMARY KEY (`sheetNum`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here IDCb information, run： show create table IDCb :

```
 |IDCb        | CREATE TABLE `IDCb` (
 `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 ......
 `sheetNum` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `fk_dvcOnsh` (`sheetNum`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_dvcOnsh` FOREIGN KEY (`sheetNum`) REFERENCES `IDCa` (`sheetnum`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=61 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

My  code of inserting into data:

```
 $conn->beginTransaction();
 $query="insert into IDCa(xxx) values('aaa')";
 $stmt=$conn->query($query);
 $stmt->closeCursor();

 $query="insert into IDCb(rrr,sheetNum) values('aaa',LAST_INSERT_ID())";
 $stmt=$conn->query($query);
 $stmt->closeCursor();
 $conn->commit();
```

Show Error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hpc`.`IDCb`, CONSTRAINT `fk_dvcOnsh` FOREIGN KEY (`sheetnum`) REFERENCES `IDCa` (`sheetnum`))fail
```

Comment: Do you have data in table IDCb, which references table IDCa, but the entries in table IDCa do not exist anymore? Why did you do all these operations without foreign key checks in the first place?

Comment: @sauerburger,yes,tables IDCb hava data. I should foreign key checks 0 first.  I have droped one column of IDCa, and IDCa data should be delete.

Comment: When you delete data in IDCa, you also have to delete all data in IDCb otherwise you have broken foreign key constraints. Foreign key checks are supposed to prevent you from deleting content in IDCa, which is still referenced by IDCb.You can extend the constraint with a `ON DELETE CASCADE` statement which will delete referenced items, when you delete an item in IDCb.

Comment: @sauerburger.Thankyou for you kindly hearted. I drop all tables, and created new IDCa and IDCb.They work fine again.Offer course, my data is gone. What a pity.